# Get ALL parents and count of children based on a where clause and left join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a one to many structure between clubs and Meetings

```
Clubs
Id    
1     
2
3
4

Meetings
Id    ClubId    MeeetingDate
1      1        2010-Mar-01
2      1        2010-Apr-01
3      2        2011-May-01
4      3        2011-Aug-01
5      3        2012-Sep-01
6      3        2012-Aug-01
```

I want to get **ALL** clubs and a count of meetings that are greater than `getDate()`

So results would be

```
Club.Id    Count
1            0     (there are 0 meetings > getDate)
2            0     (there are 0 meetings > getDate)  
3            2     (there are 2 meetings > getDate)
4            0     (there are NO meetings)
```

I have a solution but it is quite ugly! My solution contains two unions, a exists and a not exists. I am sure there is a better way but I have to confess I don't write much SQL these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.meetingDate>GetDate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count
FROM clubs c
LEFT JOIN meetings m
    on c.id = m.clubid 
GROUP BY c.id
```

And the test script as proof (or in case anyone can improve on above!):

```
;with clubs(id)
AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
),
meetings(id, clubid, meetingdate)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,1,CAST('2010-03-01' AS DATE)
    UNION SELECT 2,1,'2010-04-01'
    UNION SELECT 3,2,'2011-05-01'
    UNION SELECT 4,3,'2011-08-01'
    UNION SELECT 5,3,'2012-09-01'
    UNION SELECT 6,3,'2012-08-01'
)
select c.id, SUM(CASE WHEN m.meetingDate>GetDate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count
from clubs c
left join meetings m
on c.id = m.clubid 
group by c.id
```

Comment: Superb, never knew you could put a case inside of a SUM. I really need to freshen my SQL skills.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid oversight on my part. Here:

```
Select a.clubid, isnull(b.meetingcount,0) meetingcount    From clubs a
Left outer join (select clubid, count(*) meetingcount
                               From meetings 
                            Where meetingdate>getdate
 Group by clubid) b
On a.clubid=b.clubid
```

Comment: Meeting count returns NULL for zero meetings and getDate should be getDate(). Small issues I know, thought I would point it out though.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.id, count(m.id) as Count
from Clubs c
  left outer join Meetings m
    on c.id = m.clubid and 
       m.meetingdate > getdate() 
group by c.id
```

Comment: @Jamiec This does return the correct results as for club Id's of 1,2,4 I get zero count, I am wondering why there is an issue.

Comment: You're absolutely right, there was a subtle difference between this one and the other. @David W's uses `COUNT(*)` this uses `Count(m.id)` which makes it give correct answer.